# Save multiple photos from Mail on iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, photos, files.app

I send a lot of emails to myself from my Mac to my iPhone containing logos that I am designing, normal pictures or otherwise.  However, I have a problem with the Mail app.  Whenever I send too many photos, or photos that are very big, I have to go through the message and save each photo individually to Photos.  Whenever I send small, or just a few pictures, when I hold my tap on the picture, it will give me a prompt to save all of the pictures in the email.

My question:  Is there any way to save all of the pictures from an email, no matter the number or size of the photos?  Screenshots would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I found the way to do it.  It's actually really simple.

Just tap the Forward/Reply icon:

[image]

Then press the save button:

[image]

Hope this helps someone in the future!